# Change axis items and update grid ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

i have a plot that i've done using `R` and `ggplot2`. I would like to change the items on the x axis from 2,6,8 to 3,6,9 and update the grid. I googled around but i could only change the items with `plot = plot + xlim("3","6","9")` but this did not update the grid. How can i get it? Thank you.

Here the original plot(1) and what i got after xlim (2)

[image: Original plot]

[image: After xlim]

Comment: Check `scale_x_*`: `plot + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(3, 6, 9))` should do the trick. There's also `limits` argument if you wish to shift the plotting region.

Comment: @tonytonov thank you! post an answer, i will accept it. Works very fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate x and y axis with [`scale_x_*`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html) and `scale_y_*` functions, respectively. Here's a simple example for `mtcars`:

```
# base plot, x axis breaks at 10, 15, ..., 35
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()

# breaks specified manually
p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(12, 22, 32))

# same, with plotting region altered
p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(12, 22, 32), limits = c(0, 40))
```

Output:

[image]
[image]